# How to run the tomcat cookbook downloaded from chef supermarket?

Tags: tomcat, chef-infra, devops, cookbook

I'm quite  a newbie on Chef and I'm trying to do the first steps, so sorry for the simply question and for mistakes..

I've followed the official tutorial so I've concepts quite clear and I've seen how to build a cookbook, how to check using kitchen converge and how to upload it on Chef Server.

Now I'd like to build a simple cookbook that use the tomcat cookbook downloaded from chef supermarket.

I havent'd found a tutorial / examples for this so, you know something that could be useful please give me the link.

What I've tried to do:

1. my cookbook name is `test` and I've generated it using `chef generate cookbook test`
2. I've modified the `kitchen.yml` file  for my target platform that is CentOS 7 so  `- name: centos-7`
3. I've created my kitchen instance with the command `kitchen create` and then the command `kitchen converge`
4. tested if my SSH connection is working with the command `kitchen
   exec .c whoami`
5. all work fine untill now
6. I've seen that on Chef supermarket there is a cookbook named `tomcat` (ref. https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/tomcat)
7. I've modified `Berksfile` in this way

> ```
> source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'
>
> metadata
>
> cookbook 'tomcat'
> ```

Then I've modified `metadata.rb` adding  `depends 'tomcat', '~> 3.0.0'`

Now, how have I to modify my `default.rb` recipe (or other files ...), to obtain a working cookbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good practice to run `berks install` after change to `Berksfile`, it will update `Berksfile.lock`. Then, `kitchen converge` will transfer all files to the VM. In `default.rb` of your cookbook you should use tomcat's cookbook resources as [described in the README.md](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/tomcat#example). For example:

```
tomcat_install 'helloworld' do
  version '8.0.36'
end
```